# Does $\phi(a)=n!$ have finitely many solutions in integers?

Tags: number-theory, gamma-function, totient-function

I tried to treat solution of $\phi(a)=n!$ in integers such that $\phi(n)$ is the Euler totient function and $a$ is an integer, for $a=n$ it's clear that there is no solution because $\phi(n)<n<n!$. Some solutions I got by wolfram alpha are mentioned [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+in+integers+phi%28a%29%3Dn%21&wal=header). For instance, we have $(a,n)=(9,3)$ and $(-9,3)$, $(7,3)$ and $(-7,3)$ ,$(6,2)$ and $(-6,2)$, $(4,2)$ and $(-4,2)$,$(3,2)$ and $(-3,2)$, $(2,0)$ and $(-2,0),(2,1)$ and $(-2,1)$, $(1,0)$ and $(-1,0)$. I suspect there are finitely many of them, but this needs a proof. My question here is: When does $\phi(a)=n!$ have a solution in integers? Does it have a finite number of solutions?

Comment: Try using the fact that $\phi$ is multiplucative.

Comment: Please list the solutions you know.

Comment: I have done that

Comment: There's not really any point in considering negative values of $a$.

Comment: Another solution is $\phi(6293) = \phi(7)\phi(29)\phi(31)=7!$, and thus the corresponding $\phi(100688) = \phi(16)\phi(7)\phi(29)\phi(31)=8!$ and $\phi(1359288) = \phi(8)\phi(27)\phi(7)\phi(29)\phi(31)=9!$.

Comment: See [OEIS sequence A055506](https://oeis.org/A055506).

Comment: @RobertIsrael, Thanks so much , I didn't get attention to it however I did some search about it in OEIS

Comment: What about the main question whether infinite many solutions exist ?

Comment: @Peter,Note that if phi(x) = n!, then x must be a product of primes p such that p - 1 divides n! , this means that it has infinity many solutions

Comment: @zeraouliarafik Sorry, but I cannot follow this argument. How can we be sure that infinite many $n!$ are totient numbers ?

Comment: The copy of this question is posted [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/365024/51189)

Comment: Is it known whether every factorial is a totient number ?